# Case Insensitive search in elasticserch on include field

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive

I have a below query which does a case sensitive search in ES on word "Windows".

```
GET /record_new/_search
{"size":0,
"aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",
                "include": "Window.*", 
                  "size" : 10000,
                  "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to do a case insensitive search on the include property. How can this be done.

Comment: a [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query should help with case insensitive search.

Comment: @harishkb  with the match query, I get an output with different documents. I wanted to have all the unique values in a single bucket based on the term being search(hence using include).